# Can I say 'I knew I will go through it all'

Tags: modal-verbs, future-time

If I'm talking about the past where I was sure exactly that I will do something, can I use two tenses - past and future in one sentence?

For example:

> I knew I **will** **go** through it all.

Thank you!

Comment: You might google for "[future in the past](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-in-the-past)", Tanya. (0:

Comment: I found a related question at ELL: **"[Can “revolution that would transform” be rewritten as “revolution that transformed”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67421/can-revolution-that-would-transform-be-rewritten-as-revolution-that-transform)"**

Comment: I don't think you can logically know in the past what you *will* do in the future, only what you *might* or *would* do. Because it hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 2):

According to the rule of the sequence of tenses there should be 'would' instead of 'will'.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not correct grammatically. You should use would which is the past of will. You use would If you refer to future time from the point view of the past.  So the correct sentence is:

I knew I would go through it all.

Comment: And if I want to say in the poem:
Sometimes it's hard to believe that you will ever achieve your goal.

Is it right or here I also should use 'would'?

Comment: Tatyana,  you can use never in sentences in he present, past, or future. So you are right.

Comment: So I should say:
Sometimes it's hard to believe that you would ever achieve your goal ?
Not will?

Comment: "You **will** ever achieve" is fine, and sounds more poetic since it is looking from the present to the future.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of looking back in time

> I **knew** I **would go** through it all

In the present

> I **know** I **will go** through it all

However, your original sentence

> I **knew** I **will go** through it all

sounds like you are trying to say

> At the time, I **thought** to myself, "I **will go through** it all!"

but your original sentence is not quite correct

> > I knew I **would have to go** through it all

would be better.